# Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial: Arm64 and Kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A the moment of writing supported architectures for ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) are:

- **amd64**
- **i386**
- **armhf**

Debian supports **amd64** and **arm64**

I'm trying to get a full installation of ROS working on my NVidia TX1 which runs Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) on a **arm64** architecture.

I was wondering if there are plans to support arm64 for Xenial in the near future?

I found that the repository already exists: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/
however, it does not contain ros-specific packages yet.

This is what i tried to get ROS working:

1. Adding the Debian repository (Jessie arm64) to my sources -> Cannot install ros-kinetic packages because of invalid dependencies
2. Compilation from source -> Unable to install all packages. Some of them work, some do not (rviz, rqt).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244739/ubuntu-16.04-xenial:-arm64-and-kinetic/) by [marting](https://answers.ros.org/users/28111/marting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS Kinetic doesn't have a installation guide for Ubuntu ARM, but ROS Jade does. So you can refer to [Ubuntu ARM install of ROS Jade](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/UbuntuARM), follow the steps and replace `jade` with `kinetic`.

The basic steps are:

- Setup repositories, locale, sources.list and apt-key.
- Install ros-kinetic-ros-base
- Install individual packages that you need.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marting](https://answers.ros.org/users/28111/marting/) on 2016-10-05**:
Thanks! As of 2016-10-04 i can see the repository now hosts packages for **arm64** as well. So installation should be possible according the guide.

**Comment by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) on 2016-10-05**:
@marting Can you give an update if you manage to complete the installation. I was looking into upgrading my TX1 to L4T 24.2.

**Comment by [marting](https://answers.ros.org/users/28111/marting/) on 2016-10-05**:
Installation was successful (desktup-full). You might run in to trouble with `sudo rosdep init`. It fails because of an invalid SSL certificate. I've got it working by calling `sudo c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs`. See https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/12894 for more info.

**Comment by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) on 2016-10-07**:
That is great. Thanks!

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-17**:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
In this statement, should trusty be replaced by xenial ? if I'm using Ubuntu 16.04?